# jsreport with external css file

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

I'm using `jsreport` to render my html files to pdf. In these files, I refer to external css files. But it looks like that the phantom js doesn't like it and the css styling is not applied.
Any reason or idea on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please check following:

- is it working when you switch to html recipe?
- is it a full absolute path to the external css?
- isn't the css behind some authentication and your browser just has valid cookie which phantomjs doesn't?
- isn't the css served over https? this should work, but could be a problem in some minor circumstances

Here you see it works in playground:
https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/bkHyoe7fle/3

Comment: 1.It works
2.Yes , and it also doesn't work when the css is referred locally or externally.
3.There's no authentication
4.It's served over both http and https , but neither works
It doesn't work in the playground too !

Comment: We found the problem , actually it was due to the print style of bootstrap. It looks like that the print style of bootstrap is very different from the original look.

Comment: Oh, yes. The bootstrap is not very good for pdf reports because of all the responsiveness.